# Draw pattern in Java using numbers and (*)

Tags: java

I'm trying to write a program using Java, that (outputs) the following pattern depending on an input (integer) (n = 5):

```
0********1
23******45
678****901
2345678901
```

As you noticed:

- input(3) represent 3 rows
- single row digits (n * 2)
- Digits should start from 0 to 9 and then repeat until the pattern is fully done
- First row should have only 2 numbers (start 0 end 1)
- (*) will be in between
- Next row should have 4 numbers (start 23 end 45) and so on

How can this program written?

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class b_test_2 {
    public static void main (String arug[]) {

        String star = "*";
        int star_count, digit = 0;

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Please type a number (int)");
        int n = sc.nextInt();

        while (n != 0){
            star_count = n * 2 - 2;
            for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
                System.out.print(star);
                i = i + 1;
            }
            String stars = star;
            n = n - 1;

            for (int i2=0; i2<n; i2++) {
                System.out.print(star);
                i2 = i2 + 1;
                int x = 0;
                x = digit;
                x = x + 1;
                if (x == 10){
                    x = 0;
                    System.out.print(digit + stars + digit);
                }
            }


        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are any parts missing in your code, but you also seem to make it more complicated than it is.

To illustrate, and hopefully help you to go in the right direction, here is compact code to do it. Do not hand in this code unless you fully understand how it works.

```
static void printPattern(int n) {
    for (int row = 1, digit = 0; row <= n; row++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < row; i++, digit = (digit + 1) % 10)
            System.out.print(digit);
        for (int i = (n - row) * 2; i > 0; i--)
            System.out.print('*');
        for (int i = 0; i < row; i++, digit = (digit + 1) % 10)
            System.out.print(digit);
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

*Test*

```
printPattern(4);
```

*Output*

```
0******1
23****45
678**901
23456789
```

I case you haven't learned it yet, the `%` operator calculates the *remainder* after division.

Comment: Andreas that was mind-blowing for me, I have been reading through it and understand every single detail in your marvelous code. WOW!
I couldn't stop thinking about how could I become so genius like you.
I am sorry to ask, but since you truly helped me understand how to solve this problem, do you have any tips for me to be more direct and code simpler and clearer?

Thanks as well for describing what % means, yes I know that it is a remainder, but what I know is a drop in your ocean :)

Comment: @always_trying Sorry, for me it's just years of experience. I learned to program before there was an internet, so how I learned simply won't apply to you.